# Can not store timestamp to MariaDB

Tags: php, html, mariadb

Greetings fellow programmers, I am programming an online shopping website using HTML+PHP, everything is working smoothly, now I have reached the point where the client has their items stored into their shopping cart and wish to check-out, I dont have a real payment process so when the client presses on check-out it is considered as if they paid and I create an order in the database.

I have a table called orders_id where I store id(Primary key - auto increment) , userID(foreign key to ID in users table) and date which is the current timestamp.

this is the part of code that activates the button:

```
<form action="createOrder.php" method="POST">
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" class="filled-button" class="payBtn">Checkout</button>
</form>
```

and this is createOrder.php code:

```
<?php 
  
include 'db.php'; 
session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
        $userID=$_SESSION['id'];
        $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders_id (userID,date) VALUES (?,?);";
        $stmt= mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"is",$userID,$timestamp);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        header('Location:index.php');
    }
    else
        header('Location:login.php');
}
?>
```

but whenever I press checkout, the browser opens createOrder.php page with a blank page and does not update anything in the database

NOTES:

- The database works smoothly
  -The variable names are matching what is set into the database
- I literally have no idea why is this wrong.

Thanks for the help and everyone who puts effort to help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: try putting your sql query in try catch block and see if there is an error

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add name to your button:

```
<button 
    name="submit"
    class="btn btn-danger" 
    type="submit" class="filled-button" class="payBtn"
>Checkout</button>
```